# Is there Point3D?

Tags: c#, .net, point

Is there a built in type Point3 in .Net?
Some kind of this

```
public class Point3D
{
    public double X { get; set; }
    public double Y { get; set; }
    public double Z { get; set; }
}
```

but built in. It is not hard to implement it myself, but..

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.media3d.point3d.aspx

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting` has [`Point3D`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.datavisualization.charting.point3d.aspx) class.

> Represents the coordinates of a three-dimensional (3D) data point. This class is used when performing custom drawing with 3D charts.
>
> - **X**     Gets or sets the X coordinate of a 3D point.
> - **Y**     Gets or sets the Y coordinate of a 3D point.
> - **Z**     Gets or sets the Z coordinate of a 3D point.

Also has [`Point3D`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.media3d.point3d.aspx) structure.

> Represents an x-, y-, and z-coordinate point in 3-D space.

Comment: True enough. But if your code does not already use one of these libraries, it would be silly to add a dependency on them for such a simple data-storage class. Just define it yourself.

Comment: I realize I'm late to the party on this one but another advantage of you own class is that you can make it handle unit conversions if necessary.

Comment: @TerryTyson - or use a built-in class, and define extension methods.

Answer (score 12):

`System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting` has a `class` [Point3D](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.point3d?view=netframework-4.0)

- `float X, Y, Z`
- System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.dll (WinForms)
- .NET Framework >= 4.0

`System.Windows.Media.Media3D` has a `struct` [Point3D](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.media3d.point3d?view=netframework-3.0)

- `double X, Y, Z`
- PresentationCore.dll (WPF)
- .NET Framework >= 3.0
- .NET Core >= 3.0

I know that Vector3D is not a Point3D, but if you just want a `struct` with X, Y, Z:

`System.Windows.Media.Media3D` has a `struct` [Vector3D](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.media3d.vector3d?view=netframework-3.0)

- `double X, Y, Z`
- PresentationCore.dll (WPF)
- .NET Framework >= 3.0
- .NET Core >= 3.0

`System.Numerics` has a `struct` [Vector3](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.vector3?view=netframework-4.6)

- `float X, Y, Z`
- System.Numerics.dll
- .NET Framework >= 4.6
- .NET Core >= 1.0

Only `System.Numerics.Vector3` *does NOT depend* on WinForms or WPF!

Comment: Perhaps worth noting, `System.Windows.Media.Media3D` also contains `Matrix3D` and `Quaternion`, so if you intend to do any transformations on your points, it's probably the correct choice.

Comment: is there any benefit to using these structures vs rolling my own?

Comment: @johnktejik you can use many useful methods like https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.vector3?view=net-8.0#methods

Answer (score 3):

- [DirectX](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee780367%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) has a Microsoft.DirectX.Vector3 Structure, but will it be overkill for your application?
- [XNA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_XNA) has class [Microsoft.XNA.Framework.Vector3](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.vector3.aspx)
- [Unity3D](http://unity3d.com/%E2%80%8E) has a [Vector3](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Vector3.html) class for Representation of 3D
  vectors and points.
- [OpenTK](http://www.opentk.com/files/doc/struct_open_t_k_1_1_vector3.html) also represents a 3D vector using three single-precision floating-point numbers.